# How to fix skipping content, empty page while create PDF using itextpdf java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am facing below issues also showing my PDF Result

```
Profile :Result of my Pdf
Name    :Muthuramalaingam
Age     :29
Details:


address:abcd, country, code.
```

1. 1st page contain up to `details:` But the content isn't printed on 1st, 2nd page. Only printing 3rd, 4th page. Address details are printed on 5th page.
2. How to avoid skipping of the content and empty pages.
3. Details contain with html element, though I am using XMLParser to parse it as `ElementList`.

   ```
   for (Element e : elements) { cell.addElement(e); } table.addCell(cell);
   ```

I am also using `pageEventHandler` which extended `PdfPageEventHelper`.
I have overriden with `onStartPage()` & `onEndPage()` both method itself. I am using `columnText.showTextAligned` method.

How to fix the content skipping issue. Looks not good if first page half of the page is empty.
[image]

Comment: What is this question about? Can you rephrase your question so that people can understand what you're asking?

Comment: Have you tried applying `table.setSplitLate(false)`? (This is merely a wild guess; please do improve you question by supplying a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if you want better answers.)

Comment: @mkl Wrong use of the page events could also be a problem. However, it's hard to tell without an SSCCE.